# How can i print a link within a document.write?

Tags: javascript, html

im making a timetable that when opened gives me the zoom links to my classes and tells me what classes i have in the day.

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getDay()
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;

  if (n == 1) {
    document.writeln("Monday")
    document.writeln("you have 2 classes today X and Y and the zoom links are: ...);


    }
```

Comment: Which link do you mean?

Comment: `document.write()` lets you write arbitrary HTML (provided the document is not "closed", ie. fully loaded). It's generally bad practice but for something minor like a personal project that this seems to be, it should be fine. Just put whatever HTML you want in there.

Comment: i know its not the best but its the one my teacher has taught me yet. i want the link to be to the zoom meeting i have in that day.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write`, but append elements to some wrapper:

```js
(function () {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var links = {
    'http://example.com': 'Example1',
    'https://example.com': 'Example2'
  };
  
  for (link in links) {
    tag = document.createElement('a');
    tag.setAttribute('href', link);
    tag.innerText = links[link];
    wrapper.appendChild(tag);
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```